# call java class methods from react-native (not Android Activity java class)

Tags: java, react-native

Actually I am new here for react-native application development. And I am trying to develop a small react-native application with database connectivity (AWS Dynamo db). I select a java as a server side language. And I want to know, is there any possible to import java classes in react-native (i.e. accessing java methods from react-native).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, with a bit of glue code. React Native has a concept of [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) that allows you to interface with any Java code.

Once you've created your native module according to the above linked instructions, you can decorate any method on the module with a `@ReactMethod` annotation to make it available in JavaScript:

```
public class YourDynamoDBModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  // ...
  @ReactMethod
  public void arbitraryMethod(string query, Promise promise) {
      // do something with your third-party library
        Promise.resolve(yourResponse);
  }
  //...
}
```

You'll need a bit more boilerplate than that (it's all explained in the docs). Once that is in place, you can call it from JavaScript like follows:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

NativeModules
  .YourDynamoDBModule
  .arbitraryMethod('...')
  .then(result => {

  });
```

It's worth noting that all native module calls are inherently asynchronous, so if you need to pass data back to JavaScript you need to use promises (as above) or callbacks.